# Encrypt AES string with Go and decrypt with Crypto-js

Tags: go, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I'm looking for encrypt string in my Go application and decrypt the encoded string with Crypto-js.

I have been trying for hours without success, trying many of the solutions offered by Stackoverflow, github or gist.

If anyone has the solution they would save me from a certain nervous breakdown lol

My Go encrypt code:

```
func EncryptBody() (encodedmess string, err error) {
  key := []byte("6368616e676520746869732070617373")

  // Create the AES cipher
  block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
  plaintext, _ := pkcs7Pad([]byte("exampletext"), block.BlockSize())
  // The IV needs to be unique, but not secure. Therefore it's common to
  // include it at the beginning of the ciphertext.
  ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
  iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
  if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  bm := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
  bm.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)

  return fmt.Sprintf("%x", ciphertext), nil
 }
```

My pkcs7Pad function :

```
 func pkcs7Pad(b []byte, blocksize int) ([]byte, error) {
  if blocksize <= 0 {
      return nil, errors.New("invalid blocksize")
  }
  if b == nil || len(b) == 0 {
      return nil, errors.New("invalid PKCS7 data (empty or not padded)")
  }
  n := blocksize - (len(b) % blocksize)
  pb := make([]byte, len(b)+n)
  copy(pb, b)
  copy(pb[len(b):], bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(n)}, n))
  return pb, nil
}
```

My Crypto-JS decrypt code :

```
public decryptData() {
  const data = "3633fbef042b01da5fc4b69d8f038a83130994a898137bb0386604cf2c1cbbe6"
  
  const key = "6368616e676520746869732070617373"
  const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  })

  console.log("Result : " + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex))
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
 }
```

Comment: For decryption you strip off the IV and use it as input for your decryption, but then you feed the **complete** data to "CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key" - imho the input should be the remaining data (after stipping off the IV). As I'm not a Go specilist the encryption looks strange - are you combining a CBC-mode encryption followed by a CFB-mode encryption? If that's the case you need to reverse this on cryptojs-side as well.

Comment: Both codes are functionally very different. In the CryptoJS code, the key is passed as a string, which is why a key derivation function is applied. To avoid this, the key must be parsed with an Utf8 encoder. In the CryptoJS code, 32 chars must be used for the IV because of the hex encoding. Moreover the ciphertext must be passed to `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` without an IV (s. Michael Fehr's comment), and also as a CipherParams` object (or Base64 encoded).

Comment: In the Go code, a CBC encryption is performed first, but the result is overwritten by the subsequent CFB encryption. CFB as stream cipher mode does not require padding, yet both codes use padding. By the way, CFB is not uncritical, because the libraries generally do not default to the same segment size. Here you are lucky, in both cases CFB128 is applied.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. I have updated my code with your recommandations but no result. Could you give me your opinion on my new version?

Comment: Thanks to @Topaco for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Topaco for your help !

Solution :

Go code :

```
func EncryptBody(data string) (encodedmess string, err error) {
  key := []byte("6368616e676520746869732070617373")

  // Create the AES cipher
  block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
  plaintext, _ := pkcs7Pad([]byte(data), block.BlockSize())
  // The IV needs to be unique, but not secure. Therefore it's common to
  // include it at the beginning of the ciphertext.
  ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
  iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
  if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
  bm := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
  bm.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)


  return fmt.Sprintf("%x", ciphertext), nil

 }
```

NodeJS Code :

```
protected decryptData(data: string) {

  const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data.substr(0,32))
  const ct = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data.substr(32))
  const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("6368616e676520746869732070617373")
  // @ts-ignore !!!!!!!! IMPORTANT IF YOU USE TYPESCRIPT COMPILER
  const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: ct}, key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    iv: iv
  })

  console.log("Result : " + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
}
```